# Select From Cursor to End/Beginning of Line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the default shortcut for Windows to select everything from cursor to end of line or from cursor to beginning of line, without having to set a keybinding. I know there is a shortcut. I can't seem to find it. Anyone please?

Comment: depends on your OS, on Mac press cmd+shift+right-arrow or cmd+shift+left-arrow

Comment: `Shift+Home` (command `cursorHomeSelect`) or `Shift+End` (command `cursorEndSelect`), if you have word wrap enabled it might be `Shift+Home Shift+Home` (twice the same key)

Comment: Thank you. Shift+Home (command cursorHomeSelect) or Shift+End worked!